# USB mass storage couldn't get mounted

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, android, sd-card

It's my android phone SD card which was indicated damaged by android yesterday night, out of the blue! I put it directly to a USB port with a USB SD card holder case, so in that way I can recover it with [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), which I had experienced before on a similar situation.

I also noticed that there is a change in file system and capacity:

```
File System : RAW
Capacity : 0 (unknown capacity)
```

<s>Also TestDisk doesn't show it on its partitions list. A 2 GB SD card is not that important in price but I've a lot of files and medias which I need them.</s>

Used a mini card reader, TestDisk displayed it on its list but a **quick search** and or a **deep search** doesn't have any results `No partition found or selected for recovery`
 and then I should quit the program.

Your help is appreciated.

***Update #2***

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 04f3:0234 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Okay, this is Ask UBUNTU - Linux Mint is not ubuntu. So this is off topic, and should be asked on [linux.se]

Comment: @Tim Okay, it's not linux mint. I deleted that part.

Comment: Okay, can you [edit] to include the output of `lsusb`

Comment: @Tim output added.

Comment: Does it change if you remove the device?

Comment: @Tim Unfortunately no, nothing changed.

Comment: Think it's corrupt then :/

Comment: @Tim did you notice that part of post talking about the way it was shown in my Disks?

Comment: `there were no additional disks added to my Disks` yes, I did, why?

Comment: @Tim `but for the second time it was shown as USB Mass Storage Device`. There was a chance in detecting that SD card. So it's not that corrupt.

Comment: Well if it is no longer showing up anywhere, what would you suggest? If it is inaccessible, it's not fixable.

Comment: @Tim As a matter of fact, If I knew which things were going wrong I won't asked it here. and by the way, We all know about corruption!

Comment: Can you use Gparted to view all partitions on your device ? I had a simmiler problem, the ms-dos file system underneath the formatted part had become corrupted, gparted can fix this but it will FORMAT YOUR DEVICE REMOVING ALL DATA. I can tell you how to fix this error if you need, but any data will be lost.

Comment: Please try this to recover some data (its made by the same team as testdisk so should be good http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Comment: @markkirby Thanks for suggestions I had worked with both Gparted and PhotoRec. Gparted can't find the partition and PhotoRec also won't recover anything as it it has an unknown capacity and Raw partition. How it's possible to format if it's the last choice?

Comment: You cannot see it at all in Gparted ? it should show up but grayed out and un-formatable

Comment: @markkirby When I open Gparted and rescan partitions, It gives me an error on /dev/sdc which is my USB device: `Libparted bug found   Input/output error during read on /dev/sdc`

Comment: Can you right click the drive and delete will be the only option ?

Comment: From research I did on the libparted bug found the "bug" in this context seems to be related to faulty hard drive with dead sectors on the disk. This cannot be fixed, but in your case maybe the SD reader is a fault ? I buy cheap ones they break all the time. This is my source http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?id=16767

Comment: @markkirby delete is grayed out. I found similar topics before, but why this should happen? It's not broken or anything. I've two card reader. One is a simple Micro SD to USB converter and one has some other slots. First one doesn't work but second shows it.

Comment: OK The grayed out delete option shows the underling ms-dos RAW file system is corrupted. You cannot fix this, please dont waste your time trying as it will drive you mad. Every PC or device you put it in will read it slightly different but all will give errors. This makes it imposable to pin down the exact problem. Its not worth your time

Comment: First of do you have the MTP file system package installed?? Since Honeycomb, Android devices have starting using MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) instead of the straight up USB Mass Storage (UMS) file transfer system. testdisk does not recognize MTP (as far as I know).

Comment: @ArnovanderWeijden Thanks but What can I do with MTP file system installed then?

Comment: What I gathered from your post was that you tried to restore a UMS system whereas you should try to restore a MTP system. I must warn you though, it isn't the easiest thing to do. There are a few tools you could try, just google "restore mtp sd card"

Comment: @ArnovanderWeijden As you pointed out and gave me a clue, I suddenly found out I can do a formatting using CWM Recovery. I did it and it works! Please add your answer as well as the approach I used. I'm going to accept it.

Comment: I didn't have enough time to find you a complete answer earlier otherwise I would have added an answer. I'm glad I was able to help you.

Comment: btw. it might be possible to still recover some files from your sdcard. Just install the MTP file system package and mount your sdcard (might require a reboot with the sdcard connected). After that testdisk might be able to read the damn thing like an ordinary sdcard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as discussed in the comments of the question itself newer android devices use the Media Tranfer Protocol or MTP for short. Using testdisk to restore a MTP sdcard will not work since testdisk (as far as I know) does not support MTP.
Instead you should use a tool that can restore MTP sdcards.

[CWM (ClockWorkMod) Recovery](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/ClockworkMod_Recovery) is such a tool. Doing a formatting using this tool is a method to fix your sdcard.

You'll need to do is install it onto your phone. Next up is booting into CWM recovery and selecting "mounts and storage" -> "format sdcard".
Let it run and you're done.

[image: CWM recovery screen 1]
[image: CWM recovery screen 2]

Comment: I should add that, I had recovered my most important data with EaseUs after formatting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked to see what the Kernel is saying about the device. Plug the device into your computer and run the command `dmesg`. May shed some light on the situation. You should see references to sdx at the end of the output.

**Edit to reflect OP's comment below...**

Fire up a terminal. Stick the card in and then run `dmesg` look at the last few lines of output you should see references to sdx (x being another letter.)

As an example this is what I get:-

```
[67680.024208] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 7778304 512-byte logical blocks: (3.98 GB/3.70 GiB)
[67680.026448] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[67680.026453] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[67680.029934] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[67680.029939] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[67680.031738]  sdb: sdb1
[67820.022977] sdb: detected capacity change from 3982491648 to 0
[67825.064523] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 7778304 512-byte logical blocks: (3.98 GB/3.70 GiB)
[67825.066735] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[67825.066740] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[67825.069400] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[67825.069405] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[67825.071265]  sdb: sdb1

[67825.445884] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

I can see my card is detected and assigned as sdb with a FAT partition as sdb1.

**Edit 2...**

Have you tried to force a mount?

Create mount point. `sudo mkdir /media/mysdcard`
try a force mount. sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/mysdcard -o force

You may need to specify the filesystem type with the `-t` flag. I don't know what filesystem Android uses. I guess it may be an ext? **(Turns out the sdcard is vfat)** In any case add the `-t filesytemtype` flag immediately after `mount`. As in `sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdc1 /media/mysdcard -o force`

Have a look at this article https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB

If it works grab all the data you can off the card.

Comment: Exactly what should I look at there?

Comment: Yes, `[ 1905.643578] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc] Device not ready
[ 1905.643592] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[ 1905.643596] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1905.643599] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[ 1905.643602] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
`

Comment: It's in /dev/sdc. It's in Disk but not in gparted as it gives error.